# Displaying retrieved information from firebase database in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, database, html, firebase

I am new to Firebase and trying to retrieve static information from my Firebase Database to display in a table format in HTML

The HTML code I have is:

```
<section>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Number scenario card</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

And the JavaScript is

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
    // Loop through each tag and place a card in HTML
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
      // Generate a random number 
      var rndWCard = "/card" + Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
      // Get a database reference to our cards with random number appended to end of path
      var ref = new Firebase("https://&&**((.firebaseio.com/whiteCards" + rndWCard);
      // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the card data from database 
      ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
        // Print to console for development purposes
        console.log(snapshot.val()); 
        // Assign card to each element in the table
        elements[i].innerHTML = snapshot.val();
       },
        function (errorObject) {  // Deal with errors
          console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        });            
    }
```

But I am getting the error of:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'elements[i].innerHTML = snapshot.val()')
```

I'm guessing it's because I am returning an object and trying to display that in the table but not entirely sure as I'm new to this as I say.

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: When you use .value, you are returning a snapshot of everything at the specified node. So for example if you had a users node with all of your user data stored, the snapshot would contain every user within the user node. Likewise if you use .value on the /card10 node, everything in the node is returned. If it's a single string then it's fine. But if there are any child nodes, you will need to pull those out of the snapshot. Either way, it's a good idea to include a small textual copy of your Firebase data structure in your question. (Firebase dashboard -> Export).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
 ref.on("value", function(element) {
    return function (snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        element.innerHTML = snapshot.val();
    }
 }(elements[i]),
 function (errorObject) {  // Deal with errors
   console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
 });
```

At the end of `for` loop variable `i` is equal `elements.length`, and when `value` event is triggered at `ref` you try to get `elements[i]` element but actualy you get `elements[elements.length]` which is `undefined`.

```
 ref.on("value", function(element) {
    return function (snapshot) {
        element.innerHTML = snapshot.val();
        console.log(element);
    }
 }(elements[i]),
 function (errorObject) {  // Deal with errors
   console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the swift response, i have given you positive feedback but don't have enough reputation to do anything else. I implemented your code and ran it. I didn't receive any errors on the console but no data has populated the table for some reason.

Comment: Would you know why the data is not being displayed in the table?

Comment: What is the value returned by `console.log(snapshot.val())`?

Comment: It's the correct data from the database that I want to display in my table but the table is not displaying that data.

Comment: Is javasript in your exapmle placed after `section` tag?

Comment: Yes, it's placed at the bottom of the code, after the section tag but still inside of the body tags.

Comment: Insert the above code. What is now showing in console? How many elements? Is it `td` tags?

Comment: Hi Dmitryiy, yes it is just displaying <td></td> on the console

Comment: if you change `element.innerHTML = snapshot.val()` to `element.innerHTML = 'content'` is something happened? Is table filling?

Comment: I changed the code to element.innerHTML = 'content' but no change I'm afraid